# Python Telegram Bot нажатие на кнопку раз в неделю

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Нужно реализовать нажатие на кнопку бота раз в определенный промежуток времени. Как я вижу реализацию, при нажатии на кнопку происходит проверка условия(таймер/сверка по записанной в предыдущее нажатие дате), и при положительном ответе пользователю приходит одно сообщение, при отрицательном другое.

Пытался сделать через таймер - не вышло.

Как вижу алгоритм:

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_password(message):

```
if message.text == 'Текст копки':

    if (кнопка нажималась в течение последней недели):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Первый исход')

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Второй исход')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот Вам альтернативное решение посложнее. Для его реализации Вам необходимо изучить документацию к Sqlite3 или же реализовать что-то похожее для другой базы данных.

Немного разбавил Ваш абстрактный пример для наочности :)

Результат на практике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код решения:

```python
import sqlite3
import datetime
import telebot
from telebot import types

# Задаем токен бота
TOKEN = '{Ваш токен}'

# Создаем экземпляр бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

# Создаем таблицу в базе данных
conn = sqlite3.connect('button_clicks.db')
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS button_clicks
                  (user_id INTEGER, last_click TIMESTAMP)''')
conn.commit()

# Обработчик команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start_command(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton("100$ раз в неделю", callback_data="hundred_click"))
    bot.send_message(user_id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку, чтобы получить 100$.", reply_markup=markup)

# Обработчик нажатия инлайн кнопки
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'hundred_click')
def handle_button_click(call):
    user_id = call.from_user.id
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()

    # Получаем дату последнего нажатия кнопки из базы данных
    conn = sqlite3.connect('button_clicks.db')
    with conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT last_click FROM button_clicks WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
        last_click = cursor.fetchone()

    if last_click is None or (current_time - datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(last_click[0])).days >= 7:
        # Если последнее нажатие было более недели назад или в базе данных нет записи о нажатии, отправляем первое сообщение
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Поздравляем! Вы получаете 100$.')
        conn = sqlite3.connect('button_clicks.db')
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('REPLACE INTO button_clicks (user_id, last_click) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, current_time.isoformat()))
    else:
        # Если последнее нажатие было менее недели назад, отправляем второе сообщение
        last_click_date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(last_click[0]).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        bot.send_message(user_id, f'Вы уже получали 100$ на этой неделе. Дата вашего последнего получения: <b>{last_click_date}</b>.', parse_mode='html')

    conn.close()

# Запускаем бота
bot.polling()
```

Comment: Этот пример будет делать проверку на каждого пользователя по chat id, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, примерно так. Каждый пользователь, который нажал на кнопку получает свой уникальный отсчет времени, который хранится в БД. Таким образом, когда пользователь пытается выполнить действие снова, база данных проверяется находится ли он там и когда именно он выполнял свое действие. А именно сравниваниет прошло ли 7 дней с последнего выполнения этого действия для этого конкретного пользователя.